# Возможность скрывать/помечать вопросы (хотя бы на время), на которые не можешь или не хочешь давать ответ

Tags: предложение

Мой Workflow такой:

1. Открываю SO (либо список всех вопросов, либо по какой-то конкретной метке).
2. Смотрю по порядку список новых вопросов.
3. Если могу ответить на вопрос – отвечаю.
4. Если не могу – смотрю следующий.

Неудобство состоит в том, что вопросы, пропущенные на шаге 4, остаются в ленте.

Мне кажется, было бы удобно сделать в вопросах кнопку "Не показывать больше этот вопрос" или "Не знаю ответ", чтобы непонятный или слишком сложный для меня вопрос не появлялся повторно в ленте вопросов.

Может быть уже есть такая возможность, но я о ней не знаю? Или я делаю что-то не так, и есть более удобный workflow на SO?

**UPD**

Прочитав первый ответ, решил добавить, что нежелание видеть вопрос в списке появляется не только из-за его непонятности или сложности. Есть ряд других причин:

- на вопрос уже дано множество ответов, но автор так и не засчитал ни один из них как решение
- я уже ознакомился с решением по этому вопросу и он мне больше неинтересен
- я именно сейчас не знаю ответа на этот вопрос, поэтому хочу вернуться к нему позже (вместо того, чтобы регулярно видеть его в ленте среди других)
- я считаю этот вопрос слишком тривиальным, поэтому хочу оставить его другим менее опытным участникам (не хочу отвечать на всё подряд, на слишком элементарные вопросы, которые ниже моей квалификации по сложности)

В общем, желание скрыть вопрос (хотя бы на какое-то время) может быть вызвано множеством разных факторов. Не только теми, которые я обозначил в начальном посте.

Comment: Фильтровать отдельные вопросы нельзя. Только при наличии конкретной метки. В принципе, как метку можно менять по схеме "обычная-игнор-избранная", так можно было бы сделать и для вопроса. По той же звездочке, что сейчас. Но надо еще подумать как всё это отменить при желании. Ведь вы же не будете видеть вопрос, если он скрыт.

Comment: @alexolut, отменять не понадобится, если сделать кнопку "скрыть на время". Например, "скрыть вопрос на 1 день".

Comment: а если захочется раньше снять невидимость? Человек же он такой, существо непостоянное :)

Comment: @alexolut, согласен. Человек иррационален. На этот случай можно сделать вкладку в ЛК: "скрытые вопросы". Или дополнительный таб: "Скрытые" в общем списке вопросов. Думаю, что вопрос точной реализации уже зависит от разработчиков SO.

Comment: Собственно, [идея не нова](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73719/339911), как оказалось.

Comment: @alexolut, да. Моя идея такая же. Собственно, раньше я обитал на форумах. Там мой workflow был таким: открыть непрочитанные сообщения – прочитать – если могу ответить, то дать ответ. Соответственно, стэк непрочитанных всегда заканчивался в какой-то момент. А на SO я не могу контроллировать, что прочитал, а что нет. У меня получается в ленте каша из просмотренных и непросмотренных вопросов, поэтому я и пришёл на мету с этим предложением.

Comment: Ну, я так понимаю, по ссылке есть решение в виде юзерскрипта для хрома. Официального ответа от администрации нет.

Comment: @alexolut, там же можно понять, что это решение не очень крутое: я захожу на SO с разных девайсов. Скрытое на компе не будет скрыто на мобилке, поэтому я бы подумал, как ещё можно привлечь внимание администрации к этой фиче. Я, честно говоря, недели две на SO вырабатывал оптимальный workflow из-за отсутствия "Непрочитанных" (как на форумах). Это сейчас уже попривык к этому "хламу" в ленте, когда одно и то же по 100 раз смотришь повторно.

Comment: Привлечь внимание можно написав feature-request на [meta.se], и объяснив, что это не дубликат упомянутой темы. Ну, или конкурсом на упомянутом вопросе. У меня лично не возникало необходимости прятать вопросы, они либо интересны и поднимаются из-за ответов, либо закрываются как оффтоп и больше не маячат из-за отсутствия активности по ним.

Comment: "на вопрос уже дано множество ответов, но автор так и не засчитал ни один из них как решение" - это вообще обычная ситуация. По факту даже если автор отметил какой-то из ответов галкой - это не значит, что это правильное решение, это просто решение, которое подошло автору вопроса. Стоит ориентироваться на голоса к ответам, а не на галку "принятый".

Comment: @insolor, суть не в этом. Проблема в том, что некоторые вопросы "мешают" в списке по различным объективным причинам.

Comment: @rugabarbo, ну что можно сказать. На SO такой функциональности нет. Но при желании можно написать свой клиент с требуемой функциональностью, работающий через stackoverflow api.

Comment: @insolor, писать свой клиент – долго. Если и делать что-то самому, то проще тогда использовать подход с англоязычного SO – создать плагин для браузера.

Comment: @rugabarbo тоже вариант.

Answer (score 1):

> чтобы непонятный или слишком сложный для меня вопрос не появлялся повторно в ленте вопросов

Неправильный подход.

Если вопрос непонятный, то он сам снова нигде не появится - надо чтобы на него либо ответили, либо его исправили. В случае правки вопрос может стать понятным (хотя могут всё равно быть причины его пропустить). А в случае ответа стоит прочитать ответ - часто тогда становится понятно, что же именно хотел автор и можно предложить свой вариант.

Если вопрос сложный, то полезно вернуться к нему после появления ответов. Всегда есть шанс, что кто-то напишет на него хороший подробный ответ и ты узнаешь из него много нового и полезного.

> Может быть уже есть такая возможность, но я о ней не знаю?

Такая возможность есть только для меток, но не для вопросов. В профиле можно добавить игнорируемые метки и выбрать, будут ли вопросы по ним показываться затенёнными, либо вообще скрываться.

> Или я делаю что-то не так, и есть более удобный workflow на SO?

Каждый делает так, как ему удобно. Какой-то известный человек делал так с email'ами: открывал почту (без всякой сортировки) и просто смотрел письма подряд и отвечал на них до тех пор, пока ему не надоест. Писем приходило очень много, соответственно получалось, что он либо ответит тебе в течение часа, либо он вообще не увидит письмо и можно писать снова.

Comment: После прочтения вашего ответа, обновил свой вопрос. Желание скрыть некоторые вопросы не ограничивается изначально-обозначенными причинами. 

Что касается возможности скрывать некоторые метки – уже пользуюсь, спасибо.

Через вопрос про workflow я скорее призывал поделиться более удобными способами работы с SO.